# Selenium IWebElement matches selector

Tags: c#, .net, testing, selenium

Is there a convenient way to check if `IWebElement` matches `By` selector
something like:

```
bool isMatch = iWebElement.Matches(By.CssSelector("[data-role='collapsible-set']"))
```

or any way to workaround this.

I am traversing from child element looking for parent that matches certain condition

```
public IWebElement FindParent(IWebElement element)
    {
        var parents = element.FindElements(By.XPath(".."));
        if (parents == null)
            return null;

        var possibleParent = parents.First();
        var dataroleAttribute = possibleParent.GetAttribute("data-role");
        if (dataroleAttribute != null && dataroleAttribute.Contains("collapsible-set"))
        {
            return possibleParent;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.FindParent(possibleParent);
        }
    }
```

I have a parent selector that has default value that can be overwriten, and would like to reuse it, as it can be configured from the outside of the object.

```
    public By ParentSelector
    {
        get { return parentSelector != null ? parentSelector : By.CssSelector("[data-role='collapsible-set']"); }
        set { parentSelector = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CSS selectors I managed to draw this.

```
    public static bool ElementIs(this IWebDriver driver, IWebElement item, By selector)
    {
        return (bool)(driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript(string.Format("return $(arguments[0]).is(\"{0}\")", selector.ToString().Split(' ')[1]), item);
    }
```